# Fedora 34 GUI starts up with desktop selection option

Tags: fedora, gdm, fullscreen

I just installed a fresh Fedora 34, and plan to use this as a home theatre. While my Fedora starts fine, the desktop starts shrunk down, as if I am supposed to pick from one of multiple desktops as shown below:

[image: desktop]

How can I make my session start with the default desktop full screen?  So that I don't have to use a mouse and click a desktop before the screen is usable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new thing in GNOME 40, it's not possible to disable it with settings or dconf but there is an [extension](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/gnome-shell-extensions/) called [No overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/) that can switch that off.